# Why is there an unexpected keyword argument error for this Django API call?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, typeerror, keyword-argument

I am following the Django-Restful tutorial [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/2-requests-and-responses/), and I have the following code written

in views.py:

```
from snippets.models import Snippet                                              
from snippets.serializers import SnippetSerializer                               

from rest_framework import status                                                
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view                                   
from rest_framework.response import Response                                     

@api_view(['GET','POST'])                                                        
def snippet_list(request, format=None):                                          
    """                                                                          
    List all snippets, or create a new snippet.                                  
    """                                                                          
    if request.method == 'GET':                                                  
        snippets = Snippet.objects.all()                                         
        serializer = SnippetSerializer(snippets, many=True)                      
        return Response(serializer.data)                                         
    elif request.method == 'POST':                                               
        serializer = SnippetSerializer(data=request.data)                        
        if serializer.is_valid():                                                
            serializer.save()                                                    
            return Response(serializer.data,status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)      
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

in urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from snippets import views
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^snippets/$',views.snippet_list),
    url(r'^snippets/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$',views.snippet_detail)
]

urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)
```

When I run the server, I can get the normal http://127.0.0.1:8000/snippets/ to return the standard JSON response, but when I try accessing

```
http http://127.0.0.1:8000/snippets.json  # JSON suffix
http http://127.0.0.1:8000/snippets.api   # Browsable API suffix
```

I get an error that yields this traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/snippets.json

Django Version: 1.9.7
Python Version: 2.7.6
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'rest_framework',
 'snippets',
 'quickstart']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/home/myname/workspace/restTutorial/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/myname/workspace/restTutorial/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/myname/workspace/restTutorial/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  58.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

Exception Type: TypeError at /snippets.json
Exception Value: snippet_list() got an unexpected keyword argument 'format'
```

Why am I getting this error?

Edit: link to [settings.py](http://pastebin.com/kvTvaY6V)

Comment: can you post your settings

Comment: Here is a copy of the file on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/kvTvaY6V .

Comment: @user1362215 You need to obscure your secret key when you're posting your settings. And then update the question with that link.

Comment: Done. Though, this is just a tutorial I am walking through so security is not a huge issue.

Comment: Please post the full stack trace, not just the last line.

Comment: I edited and added the full traceback.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I had duplicate functions in the `views.py` file with different decorators that were near the bottom. Removing them solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
http http://127.0.0.1:8000/snippets.json  # JSON suffix http
http://127.0.0.1:8000/snippets.api   # Browsable API suffix
```

instead

```
http http://127.0.0.1:8000/snippets/?format=json  
http http://127.0.0.1:8000/snippets/?format=api
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similiar issue my error was that I was using Django's reverse module when declaring the urls instead of the reverse module of Django Rest Framework:

do not use this:

```
from django.urls import reverse
```

use this instead:

```
from rest_framework.reverse import reverse
```

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def api_root(request, format=None):
    return Response({
       #'users': reverse('users:user-list', request=request, format=format),
       'transactions': reverse('transactions:transaction-list', request=request, format=format),
})
```